# Python lists/arrays: disable negative indexing wrap-around in slices

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

While I find the negative number wraparound (i.e. `A[-2]` indexing the second-to-last element) extremely useful in many cases, when it happens inside a slice it is usually more of an annoyance than a helpful feature, and I often wish for a way to disable that particular behaviour.

Here is a canned 2D example below, but I have had the same peeve a few times with other data structures and in other numbers of dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 10))
```

[image]

```
def foo(i, j, r=2):
  '''sum of neighbours within r steps of A[i,j]'''
  return A[i-r:i+r+1, j-r:j+r+1].sum()
```

In the slice above I would rather that any negative number to the slice would be treated the same as `None` is, rather than wrapping to the other end of the array.

Because of the wrapping, the otherwise nice implementation above gives incorrect results at boundary conditions and requires some sort of patch like:

```
def ugly_foo(i, j, r=2):
  def thing(n):
    return None if n < 0 else n
  return A[thing(i-r):i+r+1, thing(j-r):j+r+1].sum()
```

I have also tried zero-padding the array or list, but it is still inelegant (requires adjusting the lookup locations indices accordingly) and inefficient (requires copying the array).

Am I missing some standard trick or elegant solution for slicing like this?  I noticed that python and numpy already handle the case where you specify too large a number nicely - that is, if the index is greater than the shape of the array it behaves the same as if it were `None`.

Comment: Is `max(n, 0)` an acceptable substitute for your `thing(n)`?

Comment: Downvote. You already have a good solution. Stop trying to be clever and over complicating things. KISS

Comment: @SchighSchagh You should provide some details behind the reasons for your opinion and post them in an answer instead.   Etiquette for [downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) is to use them for sloppy, wrong or badly written posts with no research effort shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could subclass e.g. `list` as suggested by jdi, Python's slicing behaviour is not something anyone's going to expect you to muck about with.

Changing it is likely to lead to some serious head-scratching by other people working with your code when it doesn't behave as expected - and it could take a while before they go looking at the special methods of your subclass to see what's actually going on.

See: [Action at a distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: Thats a very good point to consider. Though just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting to subclass builtin's like `list`. Only to subclass the types the OP is already working with...or creating a utility class to just wrap the effect in.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about overriding it so much, ideally I'd keep the existing slice but maybe create a new syntax... e.g. `A[-1:3]` for the usual way and something similar looking like `A[-1;3]` for a non-wrapping slice... if it's not plainly impossible, don't know how to do that in python without making a syntax error

Comment: Yeah, I see that ... but a slice is pretty universally understood to have a specific meaning, so changing that is asking for trouble however you do it IMO. Maybe a method like `obj.abs_slice(i, j)` would be an acceptable compromise ...

Comment: I should add that, while I've often used `A[-1]` to get the last element, I don't think I've _ever_ wanted or needed for `range(10)[-1:3]` to be the empty list rather than returning `[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: @wim: Creating new syntax is not something you should really think about with python. It would be best to just create a new method that does what you want with the given args.

Comment: @wim: actually, you could get away with `A[-1,3]` if you wrote a `__getitem__` method that accepts a tuple and responds appropriately. Not something I'd want to do, but it's possible ...

Comment: In numpy they have hacked in some new syntax (check out `r_` and `c_` objects), and it's useful, if a bit weird and unpythonic.

Comment: @jdi: You should edit your post to reflect that. Many people come to SO and take such answers as authority. If you think it's a bad idea - please make it clear.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you would have to create your own subclass wrapper around the desired objects and re-implement `__getitem__()` to convert negative keys to `None`, and then call the superclass `__getitem__`

Note, what I am suggesting is to subclass existing custom classes, but NOT builtins like `list` or `dict`. This is simply to make a utility around another class, not to confuse the normal expected operations of a `list` type. It would be something you would want to use within a certain context for a period of time until your operations are complete. It is best to avoid making a globally different change that will confuse users of your code.

[Datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

> object.**getitem**(self, key)
>   Called to implement evaluation of
>   self[key]. For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers
>   and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative
>   indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the
>   **getitem**() method. If key is of an inappropriate type, TypeError may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the
>   sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values),
>   IndexError should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not
>   in the container), KeyError should be raised.

You could even create a wrapper that simply takes an instance as an arg, and just defers all `__getitem__()` calls to that private member, while converting the key, for cases where you can't or don't want to subclass a type, and instead just want a utility wrapper for any sequence object.

Quick example of the latter suggestion:

```
class NoWrap(object):

    def __init__(self, obj, default=None):
        self._obj = obj 
        self._default = default

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            if key < 0:
                return self._default

        return self._obj.__getitem__(key)

In [12]: x = range(-10,10)
In [13]: x_wrapped = NoWrap(x)
In [14]: print x_wrapped[5]
-5
In [15]: print x_wrapped[-1]
None 
In [16]: x_wrapped = NoWrap(x, 'FOO')
In [17]: print x_wrapped[-1]
FOO
```

Comment: I'd rather extend `collections.MutableSequence` to ensure the API consistency, and encapsulate `list`.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't work with slices.  I can see how to generalise that though.

Comment: @wim: Easy enough. But what would you want to happen if it were a slice? Does it return None or an empty list, or trim the results to within the positive range?

Comment: Trimming to the positive range for slices.  Normal getting of negative indices should be left unchanged.  Is there a reason why you chose to use an explicit type check here rather than using `isinstance`?

Comment: Not really a specific reason to use `IntType` over `isinstance` in this case. Adding support for your slices would just require another check for `isinstance(key, slice)` and then setting `key` equal to a new slice that you create after looking at the old ones `start` / `stop` attributes.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this monstrosity of a hack of the standard Python syntax more elegant than bounds-checking your indices, which is much more clear and concise?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comments, and instinctively switched it to `isinstance`…

Comment: @NeilG: While I appreciate your intentions 1) Please don't modify someone else's answer to change an implementation detail. That is what comments are for and it is my choice to change it 2) If you are going to edit someones answer to change an implementation detail, please don't change it to broken code. Your edit was using `isinstance` in a way that fails, by testing if a type int is an instance of a type int. I edited the code to fix it.

Comment: @jdi: Sorry if I offended you, but you could just as easily have been bothered by a comment asking you to make your code Pythonic.  I think Stackoverflow is about editing — not ownership — which is why we can all edit each other's answers.  And yes sorry for introducing the minor error.

Comment: @NeilG - I would not have been offending by you offering a suggestion via  comment. And actually you are incorrect about the editing. If you notice, when edits are suggested by users to answers, it has to get approved by reviewers, and the reviewers have the option to reject the edit with one of the specific options being  that it "changes the intention". That suggests it is not appropriate to edit answers to change the approach. The edit should fix errors. Your edit was errantly accepted, being that it changed the intention of the answer *and* was broken.

Comment: @jdi: `is IntType` is a Pythonic error, my friend :)  Maybe you should a question if you believe that `is IntType` is just as Pythonic as `isinstance(…, int)`?

Comment: Not relevant here. Its not about pythonic or not pythonic. That's not a runtime error. Point out pythonic suggestions in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think this isn't ugly enough to justify new classes and wrapping things.
Then again it's your code.

```
def foo(i, j, r=2):
  '''sum of neighbours within r steps of A[i,j]'''
  return A[i-r:abs(i+r+1), j-r:abs(j+r+1)].sum()   # ugly, but works?
```

(Downvoting is fun, so I've added some more options)

I found out something quite unexpected (for me): The `__getslice__(i,j)` does not wrap! Instead, negative indices are just ignored, so:

`lst[1:3] == lst.__getslice__(1,3)`

`lst[-3:-1] == 2 next to last items` but `lst.__getslice__(-3,-1) == []`

and finally:

`lst[-2:1] == []`, but `lst.__getslice__(-2,1) == lst[0:1]`

Surprising, interesting, and completely useless.

Comment: That is interesting about the `__getslice__` behaviour.  Unfortunately it is not useful for the 2d array use case, it seems to only slice whole rows this way.

Comment: Yap, there's no `axis` notion for `__getslice__()`. Just added for fun, useless for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this only needs to apply in a few specific operations, a [simple & straightworward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) `if index>=0: do_something(array[i])` / `if index<0: raise IndexError` would do.

If this needs to apply wider, it's still the same logic, just being wrapped in this manner or another.