# What value do I use in a slicing range to include the last value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Imagine some numpy array, e.g. `x = np.linspace(1,10)`.

`x[i:j]` gives me a view into `x` for the range `[i,j)`.
I love that I can also do `x[i:-k]` which excludes the last `k` elements.

However, in order to include the last element I need to do `x[i:]`.

My question is this: How do I combine these two notations if I for instance need to loop over `k`.

Say that I want to do this:

```
l = list()
for k in [5,4,3,2,1]:
    l.append(x[:-k])
l.append(x[:])
```

What annoys me is that last line. In this simple example of course it doesn't do much of a difference, but sometimes this becomes much more annoying. What I miss is something more DRY-like.

The following snippet course does NOT yield the desired result, but represents the style of code I seek:

```
l = list()
for k in [5,4,3,2,1,0]:
    l.append(x[:-k])
```

Comment: How does the result produced by that last snippet differ from your desired result? I'm not entirely clear on what you're actually trying to produce.

Comment: @MattBall The last snippet, when `k=0`, will evaluate `x[:-0]`, which is an empty array, as opposed to `x[:]` which is the complete array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python lists/arrays: disable negative indexing wrap-around in slices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410615/python-lists-arrays-disable-negative-indexing-wrap-around-in-slices)

Comment: If you are certainly inside numpy `np.iinfo(np.intp).max`, is a possible magic value. Edit: oops, of course not negative...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain, but since `-0` is the same as `0`, there is no easy solution.

One way to do it would be:

```
l = list()
for k in [5,4,3,2,1,0]:
    l.append(x[:-k or None])
```

This is because when `k` is 0, `-k or None` is `None`, and `x[:None]` will do what you want.  For other values of `k`, `-k or None` will be `-k`.

I am not sure if I like it myself though.

Comment: In short, the value `None` can be used as the end value of a slice operation to take the remaining elements in the array (i.e. `l[:None]` is the same as `l[:]`).

Answer (score 11):

You can't, because -0 doesn't slice that way in python (it becomes 0)

You could just do the old school:

```
l = list()
for k in [5,4,3,2,1,0]:
    l.append(x[:len(x)-k])
```

Comment: +1 when I had this same issue, this was the simplest and clearest solution

Answer (score 6):

The value `None`, in a slice, is the same as putting nothing there. In other words, `x[:None]` is the same as `x[:]`. So:

```
l = list()
for k in [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,None]:
    l.append(x[:k])
```

However… this code is a lot easier to write as a list comprehension:

```
l = [x[:k] for k in (-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,None)]
```

Or… you might want to look at whatever it is you're trying to do and see if there's a higher-level abstraction that makes sense, or maybe just another way to organize things that's more readable (even if it's a bit more verbose). For example, depending on what `x` actually represents, this might be more understandable (or it might be less, of course):

```
l = []
for k in range(6):
    l.insert(0, x)
    x = x[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this, then:

```
l = list()
for k in [5,4,3,2,1,None]:
    l.append(x[:-k if k else None])
```

If `x` is simply `range(10)`, the above code will produce:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```