# numpy negative indexing a[:-0]

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use array slicing to trim my array 
i.e.

```
a_trimmed = a[trim_left:-trim_right]
```

this is great, except if `trim_right` is 0, I get `a[trim_left:0]`, which is an empty array.

I suppose I can could it to

```
a[trim_left:a.shape[0]-trim_right]
```

but it's uglier. What's the cleanest way to express this?

Comment: a[trim_left:] may be?

Comment: @m9_psy, yes that's my desired behavior, for a[:-0] to be equal to a[:] instead of a[0]. I don't want to add an extra conditional to check if trim_right == 0.

Comment: Why not make `trim_right` and `trim_left` default to `None` instead of `0`?  (That way they'll have the desired effect.) Otherwise, you'll have to do `trim_right = None if trim_right == 0 else trim_right`.

Comment: I find your supposed from quite concise and easy to read.

Comment: @JoeKington he may be slicing in a loop

Comment: @JoeKington `trim_right = trim_right or None` works the same

Comment: @zhangxaochen - Also, `-None` wouldn't work, anyway, so my suggestion would just add more work. Good point.

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13410615/674039

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`None` is a valid slice endpoint:

```
a[trim_left:-trim_right or None]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not that ugly IMHO. the only way I can come up with to make it shorter is replacing `a.shape[0]` with `len(a)`