# modify numpy array to return `nan` out of bounds?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there anyway to create a numpy array that returns `np.nan` when indexed out of bounds? Eg

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
x[1] # 2
x[-2] # np.nan
x[5] # np.nan
```

The closest thing I found was `np.pad`.

I know I could write a wrapper class, but I was wondering if there's any efficient numpy way to do it.

Comment: `x[-2]` is valid right? Numpy supports negative indices. Would you like to override this feature?

Comment: This seems like something that scipy people would have to add to numpy. I don't think numpy has this option. You can though use try and except, if index not found, return np.nan or something like that. That's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: why don't you just `try except`

Comment: @J.Doe: cant. negative indices are valid in numpy

Comment: Why are you mentioning negative indices? `x[-5]` will throw `IndexError` same way as `x[5]` afaik.

Comment: @Jeppe: but `x[-1]` won't

Comment: Ah I understand now, you want to disable negative indexing. In that case I think you need a wrapper, exactly like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410615/python-lists-arrays-disable-negative-indexing-wrap-around-in-slices) and in `__getitem__` you can then also check if the index is out of bounds manually or with a try/except. I don't think you can monkeypatch a `np.ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [360]: x = np.array([1,2,3])                                                                        
In [361]: x[1]                                                                                         
Out[361]: 2
```

`np.take` lets you index with mode control.  The default is to raise an error if the index is out of bounds (see the docs for other options):

```
In [363]: np.take(x,1)                                                                                 
Out[363]: 2
In [364]: np.take(x,-2)                                                                                
Out[364]: 2
In [365]: np.take(x,5)                                                                                 
----
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for size 3
```

You could write a little function that wraps this in a `try/except`, returning `np.nan` in case of `IndexError`.

Keep in mind that `np.nan` is a float, while your example array is integer dtype.

Answer (score -1):

You have many choices:

- Just insert a try/except in your code.
- Create a class that inherit from np.array and redefine the indexing operator to implement the behavior
- write a simple function that does the try/except

I like the class one.